# How do I keep my Node app running as a daemon?

Tags: node.js, linux

I have a Node (Express) application running on my server, and I've set up Apache to reverse-proxy requests to it. It's all working great, as long as I'm SSHed in and running `node ~/myApp.js`.

Obviously I'd prefer to have it listed as some kind of service on the machine that automatically starts on boot and runs in the background. But my Linux knowledge isn't that great (I'm running Ubuntu 16.04).

What's the recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: Google search gave me this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-a-linux-daemon-with-node-js-on-a-vps

Comment: You can use `pm2` to manager node process as shown here https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html#pm2